# Where to store my API_URL of my NestJS backend so it can be used in Angular libs for my Webfrontend app in my NX Workspace

Tags: angular, nestjs, nomachine-nx

my stack
NX v17.2.0
Nest v10.2.0
Angular v17+
Github for devops

I have setup my nx workspace with the backend and frontend app.
I have used angular or nest libraries for various features.

I am refactoring code and don't know where to put my API_URL environment variables so i can reuse it in the different Angular libraries via import{} and can use the nx build --prod steps to flip between the pats during build time.

Any steps or direction would be appreciated.

Best case would be to have a central place for my frontend environment variables that I can use in libraries and also leverage the nx builders during deployment.